# PHP set variable via SELECT, if variable <3 do something, +1, then UPDATE database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, sql-update

In my database I have 1 table called 'members'. This table has only two fields: 'id' and 'attempts'.
There is only one row, with 'id' set to 1, and 'attempts' set to 0.

Whenever this script is run, I want to add 1 to the table's 'attempts'. After running once 'attempts' should be 1, twice should be 2, etc.

I want to set the variable $attempts to whatever the table's 'attempts' is set to.

If $attempts value is 3 or more I want it to echo "something", and then to change the table's 'attempts' value to 0.

Here's what I have already, *how can I do this?*
I'm new to php, and going through the manuals. Any hints or help appreciated. Thanks guys :)

```
$attempts = mysql_query("SELECT attempts FROM members WHERE id=1");

if (++$attempts >= 3) {
    echo "SUCCESS!!";
    $attempts = 0;
}else {
    echo "3 attempts haven't been made yet...";
}

$sql = "UPDATE members SET attempts='$attempts' WHERE id=1";
```

Comment: why do you use apostrophes around `attempts` if it's a number? Also, what's the problem of your code? It looks like it's incomplete... All you need is to continue reading the php-mysql chapter you apparently left half way...

Comment: `$attempts = mysql_query` it doesn't work like that. Read the docs. Google "mysql_query" click the link that takes you to the docs on php.net, and read how it works. While there, see that its deprecated and you should use PDO or `mysqli_` instead (that's in a big red/pink box).

Comment: you are doing it wrong ! please read any tutorial about reading data from mysql through php (i suggest this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) - p.s: mysql extension is deprecated, use mysqli or pdo instead

Comment: @Sebas there is no problem with apostrophes even it's a number, MySQL engine says 'O.K'

Comment: @AbdoAdel,  I don't think that's always the case. It depends on the database engine being used and how strictly you have MySQL configured.

Comment: He might want the sum of attempts rather than a count of the rows.

Comment: @Sebas no, that's not related to any engine or configurations, MySQL always makes automatic typecasting if column and value data types don't match

Comment: @AbdoAdel I was not the one replying to your comment previously. However, now I do: it's not because Mysql lets you do it that you should do it. It's called permissivity, and if you put in perspective with public best practices you will quickly realize it should be avoided.

Comment: I honestly don't know why the question was closed because of being unclear.

Comment: @Sebas thx, i was arguing to learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a condition to the `WHERE` clause and change the conditional statement:

Sidenote: This of course is seeing that the "attempts" column is an int type.

```
$attempts = mysql_query("SELECT attempts FROM members WHERE id=1 AND attempts >=3");

if($attempts) {
   echo "SUCCESS!!";
$attempts = 0;
}


else {
    echo "3 attempts haven't been made yet...";
}

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET attempts='$attempts' WHERE id=1");
```

**Sidenote:** You may want to put the UPDATE in the `else{...}`
and do `SET attempts = attempts +1` to increase it by 1
or reset to zero  `SET attempts='$attempts'`.

---

- I suggest to use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.
- Plus, you're using a deprecated MySQL API.

---

**Edit:**

As stated by the OP (from a comment):

The above answer won't work as mysql_query will cause `$attempts` to echo Resource id #3, instead of the actual table value.

However, you can fix this by using mysql_fetch_assoc instead.

Everything you need to add is here: [**link**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) I've included the working code below and selected this as the answer as it put me on the right track.

Many thanks to Fred for helping me out.

```
$sql = "SELECT attempts FROM members WHERE id=1"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
$attempts = $row["attempts"];
}
```

etc..

---

**Edit #2, test**

It checks to see if the "attempts" row is more than 3. If it is, it then resets it to 0.

If not, it increases the row related to the "id" by 1.

```
<?php 
$DB_HOST = 'xxx';
$DB_USER = 'xxx';
$DB_PASS = 'xxx';
$DB_NAME = 'xxx';

$Link = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($Link->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $Link->connect_error . ']');
}

$query = mysqli_query($Link, "SELECT attempts FROM members WHERE id=1");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

if($row['attempts'] >=3) {
   echo "SUCCESS!!";
 $attempts = 0;

 $sql = mysqli_query($Link, "UPDATE members SET attempts='$attempts' WHERE id=1");

}

else {
    echo "More than 3 attempts haven't been made yet..., row has been incremented by 1.";

 $sql = mysqli_query($Link, "UPDATE members SET attempts= attempts +1 WHERE id=1");

    }

} // brace for while loop
```

Comment: The variable is completely safe, I understand the theory behind your warning but in this present case, it's not subject to sql injection at all.

Comment: @Sebas I rather not take any chances. Prepared statements are better to use for any query. One shouldn't let their guard down, not in our present-day Web.

Comment: @Sebas I've made a slight edit and *suggesting* the OP to use prepared statements.

Comment: Hi Fred -ii-, thank you for taking the time to answer, I really appreciate it. I'll get back to you once I've played around with it. Safety isn't a huge concern here as I'm essentially building a childlock with nothing of value on the other side. I'll look at updating to mysqli once I have the formula down.

Comment: @StevenBlack You're welcome Steven.

Comment: ANSWER: The above answer won't work as mysql_query will cause $attempts to echo Resource id #3, instead of the actual table value.
However, you can fix this by using mysql_fetch_assoc instead.
Everything you need to add is here:
[link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)
I've included the working code below and selected this as the answer as it put me on the right track. Many thanks to Fred for helping me out.

$sql = "SELECT attempts FROM members WHERE id=1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $attempts = $row["attempts"];
etc..

Comment: @StevenBlack Thanks Steven. I have added that in my answer for future reference, cheers!

Comment: @StevenBlack I've made an edit, tested something out. Reload the answer and look near the end under **Edit #2, test**.